Alternate Column Scroll
I'm trying to implement a scrolling behavior similar to what's demonstrated in the Figma Link. The desired behavior involves alternating the scrolling of columns, where only even or odd columns scroll at a time, and they should scroll an equal amount in the y-axis.
I attempted to implement this using the react-locomotive-scroll package, but I haven't been successful. No matter what approach I take, I'm unable to achieve the desired alternating scrolling behavior.
Has anyone encountered a similar requirement and successfully implemented it using locomotive scroll or any other library in React? I'd appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code examples on how to achieve this behavior.
